# How to use if else along with type initialisation in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider a class "myArbPrec" that can be initialised using

```
myArbPrec("0.1");
```

(e.g. it represents an arbitrary precision type).

I want my code to be compatible with both `myArbPrec` and `double`. The user sets the type with templates.

There are some constants in the template classes that are used in the program such as `0.1`. These constants are to be represented in the respective type the user chooses.

My question is: how do I put a constant in the code that is initialised depending on the type chosen? Specifically, for `myArbPrec`, it should be initialised as `myArbPrec("0.1")`. For `double`, it should be initialised as `double(0.1)`.

the problem is that I cannot use `myArbPrec(0.1)`, since this converts *first* to double, potentially losing precision, and only then to `myArbPrec`. Therefore, if my template argument is `T`, I cannot write `T(0.1)`. But because `double("0.1")` is syntactically incorrect, I can also not use `T("0.1")`.

So far, I tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15199891/931303) to my problem, by writing something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T atof(const char * c) {
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(double))
        return std::atof(c);
    else
        return T(c);
}
```

However, this fails because the `else` branch is still compiled, even if `typeid(T) == typeid(double)` is always false, which makes this to fail even when `T` is `double`.

Comment: In addition to the answer, you can look forward to C++17, in which `if constexpr` is a thing that exists, e.g.: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0292r1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mutually exclusive SFINAE overloads of your `atof` function:

```
namespace foo {
  template<typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, double>::value, T>::type atof(const char * c) {
    return std::atof(c);
  }

  template<typename T>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, double>::value, T>::type atof(const char * c) {
    return T(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use of `std::atof` is AFAIK disencouraged, better use `std::strtof` (or even `std::stof` for strings)

Comment: @Superlokkus `Use of std::atof is AFAIK disencouraged`: Hmmm, could you please post sources that encourage this discouragement.

Comment: The OSX/FreeBSD man pages: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=atof&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+10.3-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html and the open group: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atof.html 
If you read the C standard you can at least find one actual reason for: They invoke UB when the result can not be represented, in contrast to the st(r)xx family.

Answer (score 0):

I think with C++17, you will be able to use your original template with an `if constexpr` and that would work.

The proposed paper is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0292r1.html).

I don't have a compiler to test that with.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution to the suggestion of @101010, you can use tag dispatching and overloaded functions:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

template<typename>
struct tag {};

double atof(tag<double>, const char *c) {
    std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
    return std::atof(c);
}

template<typename T>
T atof(tag<T>, const char * c) {
    std::cout << "something else" << std::endl;
    return T{c};
}

template<typename T>
T atof(const char * c) {
    return atof(tag<std::decay_t<T>>{}, c);
}

int main() {
    atof<double>("3.1");
    atof<std::string>("bar");
}
```