# C++ - Curious case where Template is_Pointer seems to fails

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to make the project for BinaryTree Operations, the following are the class prototype with the code in which I am having the problem.

BinaryTree Class in BinaryTree.h file

```
template <class T>
class BinaryTree
{
   public:  
       BinaryTree();
       BinaryTree(T);     
};
```

The constructor implementation in BinaryTree.cpp

```
template<class T>
struct isPointer
{
  static const bool value=false;
};

template<class T>
struct isPointer<T*>
{
  static const bool value=true;
};

template<class T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree():root(nullptr)
{
  //ctor
}

template<class T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(T data)
{
  if(isPointer<T>::value == true)
  {
   if(data != nullptr)
   {
      //Do something
   }
  }      
}
```

BinaryTreeOperations Class inherit BinaryTree Class and its prototype is defined in BinaryTreeOperations.h

```
template<class T>
class BinaryTreeOperations:public BinaryTree<T>
{
  public:

  //Constructors
  BinaryTreeOperations();
  BinaryTreeOperations(T);
};
```

While the constructors are defined in BinaryTreeOperations.cpp class

```
template<class T>
BinaryTreeOperations<T>::BinaryTreeOperations(T data):BinaryTree<T>(data)
{
  //ctor
}
```

The main function in Main.cpp file

```
int main()
{
  cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

  BinaryTreeOperations<std::string> b("1");
}
```

And now the error which g++ is throwing is

> no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are
>   'std::__cxx11::basic_string' and 'std::nullptr_t')

at line

```
if(data != nullptr)
```

in BinaryTree Constructor defined in BinaryTree.cpp class

**Here comes the issue.** I have already defined isPointer structure to check whether the given template is pointer or not. But it seems, in spite of T being std::string g++ is going in `if(isPointer<T>::value == true)`
condition.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong? Any sort of guidance will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `if` is a strictly runtime check, both branches must compile correctly even if one of them is dead.

Comment: @Bathsheba will using std::is_pointer give me a different result.

Comment: @Quentin hmm fair point any work around to this problem.

Comment: Yes: two overloads, one for pointers and one for non-pointers, dispatched using [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to do an if else depending type of type in c++ template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199833/how-to-do-an-if-else-depending-type-of-type-in-c-template). Consider using overloading with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), as @Quentin suggested

Comment: You should also take a look at [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file/495056#495056)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer

Comment: @Wasthishelpful I don't see how my case is linked to that. I am making a thoroughly generalised case. While the other question is asking to match with some cases.

Comment: @Quentin I will try overload. But I am not familiar with enable_if. Will try that and respond. If possible could you give a sample code in the answer? I will mark it as an answer and will end this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for which [constexpr if](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0128r1.html) (C++17) would have been a nice addition: your branches are going to be evaluated at compile-time **for every T you pass**.

A possible workaround is to leverage [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and define two constructor versions depending on the result of your `isPointer` predicate and let [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) do its job

```
template <class T>
class BinaryTree
{
public:
  BinaryTree();

  template<typename TT = T>
  BinaryTree(TT, typename std::enable_if<!isPointer<TT>::value>::type * = nullptr) {

  }

  template<typename TT = T>
  BinaryTree(TT data, typename std::enable_if<isPointer<TT>::value>::type * = nullptr) {
    if (data != nullptr)
    {
      //Do something (this is a pointer)
    }
  }

};
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cbf9c12c0c29a35)</kbd>

or alternatively refactor your code keeping in mind the fact that a template is exactly *a template* and when instantiated it's going to generate code for its arguments on *any* code branch it defines.

Comment: Thanks bro for giving a solution using enable_if. I was not familiar with enable_if concept. Now I wish to mark two solutions as answer for my question.

Comment: I facing a weird issue when using this on function accepting a string literal.
`template<typename TT = T, typename std::enable_if<isPointer<TT>::value == true>::type * = nullptr>
    void test(TT data)
    {
            std::cout<<" TT isPointer true"<<std::endl;
            if(isPointer<T>::value==false)
                           std::cout<<" T isPointer false"<<std::endl;
    }` when i pass test("11"), here TT is pointer but T isn't I am not getting what is going on.

Comment: Oh I got it I should have made `void test(T data)` not `void test(TT data)` my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

```
  if(isPointer<T>::value == true)
  {
   if(data != nullptr)
   {
      //Do something
   }
  }
```

This is going to get compiled for every `T`. Even though for a given `T` the expression `isPointer<T>::value` will evaluate to false, this whole thing is going to get compiled. And if `data`, an instance of `T`, cannot be compared to `nullptr`, this results in a compilation failure.

C++17 introduces `static_if`, a compile-time directive that selectively compiles chunks of code based on a compile-time `constexpr` (in itself, a mildly controversial addition). Before C++17, the only way to do this correctly is by using specialization to selectively compile this chunk of code too, in addition to the specialization for `isPointer`.

But, in any case, the answer to your compilation error is that it is equivalent to:

```
std::string data;

if (0)
{
   if (data != nullptr)
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

The fact that the code in question will never be reached does not change the fact that it must be valid, compilable, C++ code.

Comment: if(0) mean false. Don't you mean if(1). And any suggestion for this terrible terrible mistake.

Comment: No, I specifically meant `if (0)`, the equivalent situation in the question that results in a compilation error, which occurs when `T` is a `std::string`.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't call this, exactly, a "terrible" mistake. A fairly common, arcane aspect of template instantiation that's often misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

> But it seems, in spite of T being std::string g++ is going in `if(isPointer<T>::value == true)` condition.

Indeed. The entire function will be compiled. Whether the execution can ever reach that comparison is irrelevant.

A Solution: Write a function template and overload it for pointers.

```
template<class T>
void do_something(const T&) {
    // do nothing
}

template<class T>
void do_something(T* data) {
    if(data != nullptr) {
        // do something
   }
}

//  ...

template<class T>
BinaryTree<T>::BinaryTree(T data)
{
  do_something(data);
}
```

---

C++17 is planned to introduce [constexpr if](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0128r1.html), which would allow you to write a compile time conditional in-place within a single function.

Comment: Thanks. Mr.@Quentin said something about dispatched using std::enable_if in the comments of the question. I have never used enable_if could you guide me a little with same.

Comment: @Dr.Xperience you don't necessarily need `enable_if` and in this case it will only make this program slightly more verbose. However, it can be useful to avoid repetition of multiple specializations in case you did were to use a more complicated trait condition that your `isPointer`. I recommend that you take a look at existing answers on stackoverflow for how to use it.