# Why is std::is_same not working with bool

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, traits

```
#include <array>
template<typename T>
void Func(T Param)
   {
   int Val = 0;
   if (std::is_same<T, bool>::value)
      Val += Param ? 1 : 0;
   }

int main() 
   {
   std::array<int, 10> A;
   Func(A);
   return 0;
   }
```

When I compile with gcc or MSVC, I get:

`Error  C2440   '?': cannot convert from 'std::array<int,10>' to 'bool'`

Shouldn't the compiler not even compile `Val += Param ? 1 : 0;` because `std::is_same<std::array<int, 10>, bool>::value` is 0?

Comment: The branch must still be compilable, even if it would never be taken.

Comment: Did you want to use `if constexpr`?

Comment: Answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199833/how-to-do-an-if-else-depending-type-of-type-in-c-template).  Not 100% sure if we sghould dupe close it to it though

Comment: @NathanOliver doesn't look like a full dupe, specifically because accepted answer is not what OP needs here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your current scenario, when the compiler tries to instantiate `Func` template,
it sees:

```
Val += Param ? 1 : 0;
```

where `Param` has a type of `std::array<int, 10>`, so it complains.

The thing is that if clause with [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) does not remove a part of your code magically during the function template instantiation.

Since *C++17* you might use [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>)
   Val += Param ? 1 : 0;
}
```

which [solves the problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RS6hv3t3LPfRWuU3).

Before *C++17* you may do some experiments with tag dispatching. For instance, something like should work:

```
template<typename T>
auto get(const T& p, std::true_type) {
    return p ? 1 : 0;
}

template<typename T>
auto get(const T& p, std::false_type) {
    return 0;
}
```

And then:

```
template<typename T>
void Func(T Param)
{
    int Val = 0;        
    // ...        
    Val += get(Param, std::is_same<T, bool>{});
}
```

[Wandbox example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Hvsttux59HN91Flj)